# Improved IDE'ish Python command line including code completion?

Tags: python, command-line, ide, pycharm, interactive

For writing Python I currently use the excellent PyCharm IDE. I love the way it has code completion so that you often only need to type the first 2 letters and then hit enter.

For easy testing I am of course also often on the command line. The only thing is that I miss the convenient features of the IDE on the command line. Why is there no code completion on the command line? And when I fire up a new Python interactive interpreter, why doesn't it remember commands I inserted earlier (like for example sqlite3 does)?

So I searched around, but I can't find anything like it, or I'm simply not searching for the right words.

So my question; does anybody know of an improved and more convenient version of the Python interactive command line interpreter? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I indeed tried IPython before, but didn't like the large space that every command took. I just downloaded bpython however, and I instantly fell in love. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yep, `bpython` is less well known but comes with a ton of awesomeness :)

Comment: Also, if you're interested, see [this video](http://pyvideo.org/video/1568/console-applications-with-urwid) for a demonstration of some of its features. (bpython stuff starts at around the 00:30 mark).

Answer (score 4):

[`bpython`](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) is one of the many choices for alternative interactive Python interpreters that sports both of the features you mentioned (tab completion and persistent readline history).

[image: bpython screenshot]

Another very commonly used one would by [IPython](http://ipython.org/), though I personally don't like it very much (just a personal preference, many people are very fond of it).

Last but not least you can also enable those features for the standard Python interpreter:

- Tab completion: See the [docs on the `rlcompleter` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/rlcompleter.html).

Create a file `~/.pythonrc` in your home directory containing this script:

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print "Module readline not available."
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

This will try to import the readline module, and bind its default completion function to the tab key. In order to execute this script every time you start a Python interpreter, set the environment variable [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) to contain the path to this script. How you do this depends on your operating system - on Linux you could do it in your `~/.bashrc` for example:

```sh
export PYTHONSTARTUP="/home/lukas/.pythonrc"
```

(The file doesn't need to be called `.pythonrc` or even be in your home directory - all that matters is that it's the same path you set in `PYTHONSTARTUP`)

- Persistent history: See the [`.pythonrc`](https://github.com/mgedmin/dotfiles/blob/master/python) file in [*Marius Gedminas*](https://github.com/mgedmin/)'s dotfiles. The concept is the same as above: You add the code that saves and loads the history to your `~/.pythonrc`, and configure the [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to contain the path to that script, so it gets executed every time you start a Python interpreter.

His script already contains the tab completion part. So since you want both, you could save his script called [`python`](https://github.com/mgedmin/dotfiles/blob/master/python) to `~/.python` and add the contents of his [`bashrc.python`](https://github.com/mgedmin/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc.python) to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I especially like the idea of adding this to the regular python interpreter using the suggested gist. Do you know how I can set that script to always execute when I fire up the python interpreter?

Comment: Sure - by setting the [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable. See my updated answer.